# Eclipse Android Application "PlaceholderFragment cannot be resolved to a type" Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

After hours on end of R.java disappearances, along with dozens of other random problems, I have finally gotten down to a two (related) bugs - but I cannot fix them. I've looked it up many times, but there have been no other posts regarding this issue on this website or on any others. Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.yahoo.jedibradftw.audiobooksync;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
        // search
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        // settings
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}}
```

The errors are as follows:

PlaceholderFragment cannot be resolved to a type. Line 21:

```
.add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
```

Illegal modifier for the local class PlaceholderFragment; only abstract or final is permitted. Line 52:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
```

I have tried Project -> Clean and Project -> Build All multiple times, and even restarted the Eclipse client, but the problem still persists. I never had this problem before (in the old test application or this one), even though none of the coding is different. If you need more of my code, just ask, and I will paste it in. Similarly, if you need a portion of the given code explained (due to inadequate commenting), ask and I will try to explain it to you. I doubt I could explain most of it, though - I'm still learning the language, after all.

In hindsight, the use of 'placeholder' suggests that I input my own name - but this was never explained in [the guide I've been following](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html). If I tried to customize it more, it would probably end up more broken than before. If the problem truly is that simple, I hope someone can walk me through the steps I should have taken!

Comment: you have misplaced `}` in your code. You use a IDE so should be easy to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misplaced `}` in your code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
    // search
    return true;
case R.id.action_settings:
    // settings
    return true;
default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Change to

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
    // search
    return true;
case R.id.action_settings:
    // settings
    return true;
default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
} // missing
```

And remove the extra `}` at the end of code.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Thank you so much. :D I never would have seen that problem, considering it was never pointed out as an error. My action bar icons still aren't working, which is very disappointing, but it runs - and that's what matters!

Comment: I tried to accept it once I found out it worked, but I'm not allowed to accept an answer within 10 minutes of asking the question. You're marked as the answer now. :)

Comment: @user3479544 that is because the site has restriction a timer.